# How to access a Chrome Extension's icon from a content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Inside of my Chrome extension's content script, I'm trying to modify the favicon of the site to (temporarily) set it to my extension's icon. I can't figure out the correct way to reference the extension's icons from within the content script, however. I've tried:

```
    favicon.href ='/images/icon-38.png';
    console.log("set href of favicon to " +favicon.href);
```

But the value of favicon.href ends up relative to whatever site I'm on, for example: `set href of favicon to https://twitter.com/images/icon-38.png`

From my manifest.json:

```
"icons": {
  "16": "images/icon-16.png",
  "38": "images/icon-38.png"
},
```

Within my background script, I can of course refer to my icons with their relative path... but how do I do it from the content script?

Comment: You need to declare the icon(s) in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use getURL as shown in the link.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the icons as [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources):

```
"icons": {
  "16": "images/icon-16.png",
  "38": "images/icon-38.png"
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "images/icon-16.png",
  "images/icon-38.png"
],
```

And then use [`chrome.runtime.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) ([`chrome.extension.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) is deprecated since Chrome 58)

```js
chrome.runtime.getURL('images/icon-16.png');
chrome.runtime.getURL('images/icon-38.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

`chrome.extension.getURL('images/icon-38.png')`

Comment: To make this answer complete: the file also has to be declared in the manifest.json under web_accessible_resources

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL` is deprecated, and as @Katie indicates you also need to specify `web_accessible_resources`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092296/1461424).